# Retrieve Data from Database to multi select dropdownlist and Select dropdownlist (Asp.Net Core MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, entity-framework-core, viewmodel

I'm creating a Web Application using Asp.net Core 2.2 (MVC) with Bootstrap 4.3. So, I am trying to build a page to ask the user for the player info, then in other page, I want from the user to select multi players to be added to a Team, Then in the last page, I want from the authorized user to be able to add two teams for the game. My problem here, is how to retrieve players data to the Team menu and add multi select drop down list? Same thing for the game page, how can I retrieve teams data to be able to select one team?  in Entity Framework Core

Team Model:

```
public class Team
{
   [Key]
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Location { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

For the Team Controller (GET):

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddTeam()
{
   var AddTeam = new AddTeamViewModel();
   ViewBag.Title = "Add Team";
   AddTeam.GetAllPlayer = _playerRepository.GetAllPlayers().ToList();

   return View(AddTeam);
}
```

For the Team Controller (POST):

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddTeam(Team team)
{
   try
   {
      _teamRepository.AddTeam(team);
      return RedirectToAction("AddTeam");
   }
   catch
   {
      return View();
   }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class AddTeamViewModel
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string TeamName { get; set; }
   public string Location { get; set; }
   public List<Player> GetAllPlayers { get; set; }
   public Player Players { get; set; }
}
```

For the View (Team):

```
<select asp-for="Players" asp-items="@Model.Players" id="ID">
<option></option>
</select>
```

For the View (Game):

```
<select asp-for="FirstTeam"
asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Teams,"ID","Name"))">
<option>Please Select the First Team</option>
</select>
```

So, I'm expecting after the user entered the players info at different page, to be able to see it in the AddTeam page then be able to select multi players for the team. Same thing for the game, but I just need to let the user to just select one team not to be able to select many.

Comment: It's not clear what issue you are facing here, are you checking how to use a multiselect dropdown list?

Comment: In other words, I am looking for two things,

First, I am just trying to add a **Multi Select Drop list option** and the data for the list should be from the user input from different Model

Second, Just add simple **Drop List Menu** at different view to select one option instead of multi select option, and the data should be from the stored data that user added

Comment: @ssilas777 To understand what I am trying to build. I am just trying to build a site for Gaming. So, I suppose to add player, then create a new team and then be able to multi select players to be added to the team that I am trying to create